# counting number of times an id has duplicated years

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df = 
id Year Value
1  1    3
1  2    4
2  1    6
2  2    2
2  2    3
3  1    7
3  2    3
```

I want to count the number of times an individual id has a duplicating year.

Desired Outcome:

```
1
```

Id 2 has year 2 twice, that's why `1` is the outcome

So far I have tried:

```
library("dplyr")
df %>% group_by(id, Year) %>% summarize(count=n())
```

but I cannot get a single number with the count

Cheers

Comment: a single number. In this case, 1 since only one-time id and Year is repeated for a single observation

Comment: No worries, answer has been resolved. Maybe I did not explain it correctly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `table` and create counts of observation for each `id` and `year` and then calculate the ones which occur more than 1 time.

```
sum(table(df$id, df$Year) > 1)
#[1] 1
```

---

Just for completion, if we want to do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, Year) %>% 
  summarise(count= n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(new_count = sum(count > 1)) 

#   new_count
#      <int>
#1         1
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much

Comment: 1up for understanding the problem at a very early stage!

Comment: Another `dplyr` possibility: `sum(count(df, id, Year)$n > 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

**data.table solution:**

data:

```
dt<-
fread("id Year Value
1  1    3
1  2    4
2  1    6
2  2    2
2  2    3
3  1    7
3  2    3")
```

code:

```
dt[,.N>1,by=c("id","Year")]$V1 %>% sum
```

Answer (score 1):

A (fast) alternative:

```
sum(sapply(split(df$Year, df$id), function(x) any(duplicated(x))))
```

Where:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
  Year = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
  Value = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L)
)
```